# Rails 4.1.7 Heroku Error: (No route matches [GET] “/”)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

My app so far seems to be working, until I try to see it on Heroku. Checking my logs I see " Error: (No route matches [GET] “/”)"...

This is my routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'pages/landing_page'

  get 'pages/contact'

  get 'pages/about'
```

---

this is the Gemfile:

```
 Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.7'
 Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

---

app on github: https://github.com/nandoencinas/test_app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a route that matches to your root path ('/').  Which means when you go to your heroku and enter `myheroku-app.com`  Your application doesn't know which controller#action to send as a response.

However, if you put in `myheroku-app.com/pages/landing_page` (by looking at your routes), you will see your landing_page.

If `pages` is the name of your controller, and `landing_page` is your action you can put this in `config/routes.rb`:

```
root to: "pages#landing_page"
```

And now, when someone visits the root of your application (ie myheroku-app.com, they will be routed to your landing page

Comment: thanks for helping a newly. works great and it has been learned